# How can i get a value from webpage and use it on main class ? Android app

Tags: java, android, httprequest

I'm trying to read something on a web page and store it in a var called "finalresult". I read the text, i used HttpURLConnection, and i did it in doInBacgorund from AsyncTask.

I'll show you my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public String finalresult = "";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

class MyRemote extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try
            {
                //Create connection
                url = new URL("My url bla bla");
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

                connection.setUseCaches(false);
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);

                //Send request
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

                //Get Response
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                    response.append('\r');
                }
                rd.close();

                finalresult = response.toString();



            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally
            {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }
    }
```

And when i want to use the "finalresult" var in the Main Activity Class I CAN'T, because it's empty. HOW CAN I GET THAT RESULT IN MY MAIN ACTIVITY CLASS?

Txh.
By the way, i'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at Android's documentation for [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Also, I'm not sure if you're missing a bracket or something, but note that your `MyRemote` class declaration cannot be inside the `onCreate()` method.

The reason why your `finalResult` variable is empty is because you never actually used the `MyRemote` class that you implemented.

So you need

```
new MyRemote().execute();
```

in your `onCreate()` method. Also, keep in mind that because this request is **asynchronous** it would make sense to use your `finalResult` variable in the `onPostExecute()` method.

Additionally, it's not a great idea to hardcode the URL the way you did with

```
url = new URL("My url bla bla");
```

Instead it should be passed in as a parameter to the `execute()` method. Again, take a look at the documentation and it should become a lot clearer.

Comment: Thank you verry much! This is an awesome answer!